# Super atoms and their orbitals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, orbitals

I was reading a science magazine the other day when I came across an article on superatoms. I am now wondering if these structures form their 'superorbitals' in a similar way to the pi rings in benzene molecular orbitals or is something different going on?

Comment: So what are superatoms? Can we have an explanatory link?

Comment: Fullerenes certainly do form their 'superorbitals' (in fact, normal molecular orbitals, just very large) in a similar way to the $\pi$ rings in benzene. Not sure whether they count as superatoms, though.

Comment: explanatory article: https://www.newscientist.com/article/2098038-first-superatom-molecules-pave-way-for-new-breed-of-electronics/